# SQLite Get last added entry autoincremented id

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, key

I add new entries in one of my tables via `dBHelper.addEntry(e);`
After doing that I need the autoincremented ID from this new entry "e" for using it as foreign Key for other entries in a other table. How do I get this new autoincremented ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `SQLiteDatabase#insert()` in `addEntry()` - it returns a `long` return value which is the row id of the newly inserted row.

Comment: Ok this worked. Thx a lot. Ill mark this as right answer as fast as possible. :)